# How can I set the background image of multiple buttons in a certain view from a different view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, colors

Basically, I cannot figure out how to change the background image.  I have searched and searched and just cannot seem to find it.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

**Update**

Here is the code I use to show the View:
     SettingsViewController *settingsView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:settingsView animated:YES];

If anyone needs anything else to help out I'll do my best!  Thanks!

Comment: Can you type a little more and explain exactly where you want to change the bg  image ?

Comment: Why would the view be changed? Would the user do something that would initiate this?

Comment: Yes, James.  
In short, I'm making a settings page (its own view controller) for an app, to change the colors.  The user must select their color preference.  

@Legolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a messages between different views can be done by direct call of the methods (not a good architectural solution but maybe not critical for a small projects) or with an event driven model as described in an answer above. 
As for binding of a collection of objects and processing the afterward I recommend to review IBOutletCollection keyword that allows to bind multiple objects fro an InterfaceBuilder to a property with a type like NSArray.

Property declaration will look like following:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

The code to change the background for all the buttons will look like following:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
for(UIButton *button in buttons) {
    [button setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: So I put the property part in the non-settings view controller.h file and the  change the background part in the settingsviewcontroller.m file?  How do I go about linking those together then?  THanks!

Comment: I'm new to this in case you couldnt tell

Comment: You are right. "@property" part need to be put into .h file. The code that go thru buttons need to be put into .m file. In addition you will need a string "@synthesize" buttons; in a .m file to auto generate getter and setter methods for buttons property in a code. In interface builder you will need to connect "buttons" property with each button on a view that you want to be affected by the code above.

Comment: I have the "@property" part in a .h file but when I attempt to put the "@synthesize" buttons part in it says that it needs to be declared in the "SettingsViewController".  Do I need to do a #import of the view controller I'm putting the property in?  Thanks so much, sorry to be a pain!

Comment: I assume that your "settingsviewcontroller.m" file already has an import of "settingsviewcontroller.h" file. Just double-check that "@synthesize buttons;" included in "@implementation" block of settingsviewcontroller but not above or below it.

Comment: Thanks!  And one last thing.  Is there a way that I can change the color of the text in a label?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with use of textColor property in UILabel class. Or if you are still talking about button then setTitleColor:forState: method.

Comment: I feel like I'm being difficult, but in the for statement it says that  buttons is an undeclared identifier.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Check all the code changes: 
1. You should have "settingsviewcontroller.m" with defined "@property" in it. 
2. You should have "settingsviewcontroller.h" with defined "@synthesize buttons;" inside of "@implementation settingsviewcontroller"
3. Code that manipulates the buttons should be also defined in scope of settingsviewcontroller.

Comment: I figured it out a couple seconds before I checked this.  I accidentally undid my adding of the "@synthesize" Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: One last thing.  Since the buttons are in a different view controller than I am putting the code in (because I need to make a button with that code) how do I tell xcode to pass the Numbers array over to a different view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You use `setBackgroundImage:forState:` to set the image.

Regarding the different views part, it depends on how you wrote your code.  If the view with the buttons is controlled by the different view (by creating an instance and using `addSubview:`) then you can call it directly by using `instanceName.buttonName` (as long as you declare it as a property -thanks fichek).

If you don't manually add the view, instead through IB, you can have the button that controls the other button's image point to the IBAction in that class.

If neither of those options work you can always use NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: By creating an instance of UIButton and adding it to the view, you don't get to access is using instanceName.buttonName like you believe. For it to work that way, buttonName has to also be declared as a @property on instanceName.

Comment: I add the view that changes the main view's images as a subview.  So should I use NSNotificationCenter?  And if so how do I use that?  Thanks!

Comment: If the main view has an instance of the subviews then you don't need NSNotificationCenter.  If not look at the documentation, apple went out of their way to make it very clear how to use it.